# Is freezing my credit card as a form of spending control a bad idea?

Tags: credit-card

I see that my credit card company offers the ability to "freeze" and "unfreeze" my credit card with the tap of a button on their mobile app.  I'm pondering using that as an additional constraint to avoid impulse buys or using it out of laziness.  Is this a horrible idea?

The credit card company appears to market the freeze feature as a way to temporarily lock a card in case you think your credit card is stolen but aren't sure.

Thoughts?

Comment: Does not sound like much of a deterrent given "the ability to "freeze" and "unfreeze" my credit card with the tap of a button on their mobile app".

Comment: @void_ptr right but if you forget and are in line at the checkout stand...

Comment: Such `freeze` features sound like a security feature than spending hinderance. i.e.  When you go for week-long hiking,

Comment: @MikeB - Then you just get to say "hold on a sec", log into the app, unfreeze it, and try again.  Vs the embarrassment of saying "Oh, I shouldn't be making this purchase" and walking away.  Some people can do that, but I think most would err on the side of less social friction.

Comment: Related: https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/109011/how-can-sister-protect-herself-from-impulse-purchases-with-a-credit-card/

Comment: Can you define "bad idea?" I could see two interpretations: 1) will it be an effective tool? 2) will it, literally, work (as in, perform the function as you understand it without any negative consequences?)

Comment: I read "bad idea" as "Will my credit card company flag me for repeatedly freezing my card?" If the issuer doesn't care, there's no harm in *trying* this. If it curbs your spending, great! If not, you can look for other techniques.

Comment: @chepner Right. Exactly.  My credit card company advertises this feature as a protection measure in case the card is stolen (which to me implies that they're not expecting customers to leave a freeze going for lengthy periods of time).  I want to use it as an additional spending deterrent (for scenarios where I use it purely out of habit instead of my debit card.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not a **bad** idea; it's -- as [explained by void_ptr](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/109799/is-freezing-my-credit-card-as-a-form-of-spending-control-a-bad-idea#comment209417_109799) -- a **fruitless** idea.

The rest of us who had (or have) CC spending problems (except for Ramseyites<sup>1</sup>) just stick them in "the back of the sock drawer" and use a debit card until such time as they've paid off all CC debt and have ingrained the habit of living below their means.  .

I stuck mine in a basket on the shelf above my desk for four years, paying off debt, getting in the habit of living below my means and then deeply ingraining that habit.

<sup>1</sup> Followers of Dave Ramsey, who cut them up, cancel the accounts and never use CCs again

Comment: Ron, a good answer, a +1 from me, but. Celebrity and cult leader, Dave Ramsey doesn’t advocate using a credit card under any circumstance. Not for those who have learned how to manage their money, nor for those who save 30% of their income, and never paid a cent of interest ever. Your “until such time as” is a misrepresentation of a fundamental belief of “The David” and his followers.

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer point taken.  I know that, and should have made that clearer.